# List.contains on specific location

Tags: c#, arrays, string, search

there are names inside the Titles array and i want to know what names are in there and i want to place the numbers on a separate array. Example i want to get all the names with this format: "Name 1","Name 2","Name 3" but what happens is that it gets also the names with format: "Name   1","Name1","SampleName1" and "FirstNameLast" because i am using a substring. I provided the code i have below.

```
List<int> ArrayCounter = new List<int>();

foreach(Title titlename in Titles)
{
    int length = "StringFromResource".length;
    if(titlename.name.length == length)
    {
        if (!UntitledPolicyArrayCounter.Contains(0))
            UntitledPolicyArrayCounter.Add(0);
    }
    else
    {
        if (!ArrayCounter.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(titlename.name.Substring(length + 1))))
            ArrayCounter.Add(Convert.ToInt32(titlename.name.Substring(length + 1)));
    }
}
```

i want to be able to get only the names with the format: "Name 1". How do i accomplish this without using regex?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: The question seems vague, could you please rephrase it? :)

Comment: You gave some example values, but not clear what goes with what.  What does the value of `titlename.name` look like?

Comment: Also, substring doesn't perform any formatting, so when you say "the names with format... because I am using a substring" I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @AaronLS: the values of the titlename.name is just a string. any string with any format.

My problem is that using the substring returns anything that has the string "Name" in it because substring compares everything inside the source string. I want it to compare only staring from the first character

Comment: I feel like I still don't understand, because if it is any string, then "Convert.ToInt32(titlename.name.Substring(length + 1)" would throw an exception if .name is "Bob".

Comment: Is "StringFromResource" supposed to be an example of a title you are searching for?

Comment: it wont go inside that part because it failed on the condition if(titlename.name.length == length). Unless the name has same length of the string that im looking for.

and yes, "StringFromResource" is the string im looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the StartsWith function.  I'm still quite vague on what your code is trying to do.  I feel example input and expected output might better clarify what you want.  Here is some code that might help if I understand what you are trying to do.  I might be a little off with my substring functions(you might need an additional +1).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw.aspx

```
string findThis = "SomeTitle";
string name = "SomeTitle 1";

if(findThis.Length + 2 == name.Length
    && name.StartsWith(findThis))
{
  int number;
  //make sure there is exactly one space followed by an integer
  if( name.Substring(findThis.Length, 1) == " " 
    && Int32.TryParse(name.Substring(findThis.Length + 1, 1), out number))
  {
     //number now contains 1 parsed from the string
  } 
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the number is ever two digits: 22, 33, 45, etc. because it assumes only a single space and single digit.  To handle multiple digits, you'd probably need some loops, going through each char `name[i]` and testing that character with TryParse.

Comment: Yeah thats what i thought, im testing the workaround for handling non-single dgit numbers.

Comment: Another appoach would be once you get past the first space, take the entire remaining part of the string, and pass to TryParse.  If the rest of the string isn't a valid integer, it will return false.

Comment: It'd be something like `TryParse(SubString(findThisLength+1, name.Length-1-findThis.Length), out number)` but might be one off.